# body_entered signal won't emit when rigidbody collided to rigidbody

Tags: collision-detection, rigidbody, godot, hit

I have multiple rigidbody object floating away in the space. When they hit each other, they push away each. I want to destroy object if they hit something, but connect body_entered signal won't invoked when they impact each other:

```
func _ready():
    connect("body_entered", self, "destroy")

func destroy(body):
    print("HIT!")
    queue_free()
```

How do I check Rigidbody hit something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, a `RigidBody` will not emit a signal when it collides with another `RigidBody`. This is usually a good thing, as `RigidBodies` may collide frequently, and could fire many signals that you don't care about, negatively impacting performance.

If you *do* care about detecting `RigidBody` collisions, you should set [`RigidBody.contact_monitor`](http://docs.godotengine.org/en/latest/classes/class_rigidbody.html#class-rigidbody-property-contact-monitor) to `true` and [`RigidBody.contacts_reported`](http://docs.godotengine.org/en/latest/classes/class_rigidbody.html#class-rigidbody-property-contacts-reported) to a value greater than `0`.

From the docs on `contact_monitor`:

> If true, the RigidBody will emit signals when it collides with another RigidBody.